# Xcode 8.3.2: SourceKitService and lldb-rpc-server take more memory for specific project

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, xcode8

I am not using `Xcode` beta version. The issue when I try to do a `Build` or `Run` the code it takes 1-2 minute time normally. When I work more for around 5-6 my system gets stuck more. When I check activity monitor lots of memory is taken by `SourceKitService` and `lldb-rpc-server`, which take around 6 GB. After terminating those services system works fine. I am facing this issues around one week and issues come for specific single project wrote in Swift 3.

Any idea as to what the problem could be?

Comment: I also have a large project with both Objective-C and Swift. I can confirm that CPU usage, not memory usage, is very high. And I can confirm that killing `SourceKitService` relaxes my system. This looks like a bug which could be reported via Apple Bug Reporter. I am keeping it on [my own radar](https://github.com/stanislaw/Xcode-Major-Bugs).